# CodeIgniter - css file doesn't work

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have problem with css file in CodeIgniter framework. In my autoconfig file I load url and html helper. In view I have code:

```
<?php echo link_tag('application/assets/css/style.css')?>
```

but this code doesn't work. In config file my base_url is `http://localhost/CI`. My directory structure is

-application
   -assets
      -css
   -views
      -partials
      -home
I try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>application/assets/css/style.css"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('application/assets/css/style.css')?>"/>
```

but this also doesn't work.

Comment: You can't put your asset folder in application folder.

Comment: So assets folder must be in root directory?

Comment: move assets outside the applciation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your asset folder in project root, out side application folder.

Change the link to,

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/style.css')?>
```

**CI Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this work. I put assets folder in application folder because I read it in the course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use assets folder outside the application folder, something like:

[image]

Than you can call like:

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/style.css');?>
```

Comment: But should enable the helper in autoload.php file in config folder. $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','security','html');

Comment: @Tamilheartz: yes agreed

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not remove index.php from url so you should set address for css like this :

```
<?php echo site_url('assets/css/style.css')?>
```